# R: writing a function that uses a dataframe to create a frequency table of the variable by group

Tags: r, function, group-by

I have a dataset with a list of bacteria and their susceptibilities to a drug (S = susceptible, I = intermediate, R = resistant). I would like to write a function that will calculate the susceptibilities (S/total). I am using `tabyl` but it seems that may not be the best idea?

Edit: @Friede had the right idea. I am hoping to get a list of organism with their susceptibility frequencies.

Now, I'm having issues with the function. I have 2 arguments, the dataset and the variable name, but the error says object not found.

```r
pacman::p_load(datapasta,
               tidyverse,
               janitor)

demo_dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
     organism_name = c("Klebsiella pneumonia",
                       "Klebsiella pneumonia","Escherichia coli",
                       "Klebsiella pneumonia","Enterobacter cloacae","Escherichia coli",
                       "Klebsiella pneumonia","Escherichia coli","Escherichia coli",
                       "Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumonia",
                       "Klebsiella pneumonia","Escherichia coli","Klebsiella pneumonia",
                       "Escherichia coli","Serratia marcenscens",
                       "Klebsiella oxytoca","Escherichia coli","Proteus mirabilis",
                       "Escherichia coli"),
      amox_clav_po = c("S","S","S","I","R","I",
                       "S","I","R","I","S","S","S","S","I","R","S","S",
                       "S","R")
)

demo_dat |> 
  group_by(organism_name) |> 
  summarise(susceptibility = sum((amox_clav_po == "S")/n()))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   organism_name        susceptibility
#>   <chr>                         <dbl>
#> 1 Enterobacter cloacae          0    
#> 2 Escherichia coli              0.333
#> 3 Klebsiella oxytoca            1    
#> 4 Klebsiella pneumonia          0.857
#> 5 Proteus mirabilis             1    
#> 6 Serratia marcenscens          0

calculate_by_spec <- function(dat, po) {
  x1 <- dat |> 
    group_by(organism_name) |> 
    summarise(susceptibility = sum((po == "S")/n()))
  
  cat(x1)
}

calculate_by_spec(demo_dat, amox_clav_po)
#> Error in `summarise()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `susceptibility = sum((po == "S")/n())`.
#> ℹ In group 1: `organism_name = "Enterobacter cloacae"`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! object 'amox_clav_po' not found
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─global calculate_by_spec(demo_dat, amox_clav_po)
#>   2. │ ├─dplyr::summarise(...)
#>   3. │ └─dplyr:::summarise.grouped_df(group_by(dat, organism_name), susceptibility = sum((po == "S")/n()))
#>   4. │   └─dplyr:::summarise_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by, "summarise")
#>   5. │     ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │     └─dplyr:::map(quosures, summarise_eval_one, mask = mask)
#>   7. │       └─base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
#>   8. │         └─dplyr (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
#>   9. │           └─mask$eval_all_summarise(quo)
#>  10. │             └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>  11. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  12.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  13.     └─dplyr (local) handler(cnd)
#>  14.       └─rlang::abort(message, class = error_class, parent = parent, call = error_call)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur ... 10.16
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/Phoenix
#>  date     2024-01-29
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package       * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  backports       1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  broom           1.0.1   2022-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cellranger      1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  cli             3.6.1   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  colorspace      2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  crayon          1.5.2   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  datapasta     * 3.1.0   2020-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  DBI             1.1.3   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  dbplyr          2.2.1   2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  digest          0.6.30  2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  dplyr         * 1.1.2   2023-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ellipsis        0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  evaluate        0.17    2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fansi           1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  forcats       * 0.5.2   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  fs              1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  gargle          1.2.1   2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  generics        0.1.3   2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  ggplot2       * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  glue            1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  googledrive     2.0.0   2021-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  googlesheets4   1.0.1   2022-08-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  gtable          0.3.1   2022-09-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  haven           2.5.1   2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  highr           0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  hms             1.1.2   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  htmltools       0.5.3   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  httr            1.4.4   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  janitor       * 2.1.0   2021-01-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  jsonlite        1.8.3   2022-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  knitr           1.40    2022-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lifecycle       1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  lubridate       1.9.0   2022-11-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  magrittr        2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  modelr          0.1.9   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  munsell         0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pacman          0.5.1   2019-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pillar          1.9.0   2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  purrr         * 1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  R6              2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  readr         * 2.1.3   2022-10-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  readxl          1.4.1   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  reprex          2.0.2   2022-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rlang           1.1.1   2023-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rmarkdown       2.17    2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rstudioapi      0.14    2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  rvest           1.0.3   2022-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  scales          1.2.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  sessioninfo     1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  snakecase       0.11.0  2019-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringi         1.7.8   2022-07-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  stringr       * 1.4.1   2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tibble        * 3.2.1   2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyr         * 1.2.1   2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyselect      1.2.0   2022-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tidyverse     * 1.3.2   2022-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  timechange      0.1.1   2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  tzdb            0.4.0   2023-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  utf8            1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  vctrs           0.6.2   2023-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  withr           2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xfun            0.34    2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  xml2            1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#>  yaml            2.3.6   2022-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: Go one step at a time. Get code that works normally before you try putting it in a function. `demo_dat |> group_by(organism_name) |> tabyl()` doesn't work in the console, so debug that and get it working before you try putting it in a function.

Comment: I am unsure about your expected output? Simply `prop.table(table(demo_dat$amox_clav_po))`?

Comment: ... or does `demo_dat %>%  group_by(organism_name) %>% summarise(Susceptibility = sum((amox_clav_po == "S") / n()))` give you what you want?

Comment: Generally, `group_by` works with `dplyr` functions like `mutate` and `summarize` and `filter`,  I don't see any indication that `tabyl` works with `group_by`, are you looking for `demo_dat |> tabyl(organism_name)`? From these questions it's pretty clear that no one is clear on your goal. Could you show your expected output?